# How to convert Org mode file to ODT using a template and Pandoc?

Tags: org-mode, pandoc, odt

I have a file `plan.org` with following contents:

```
* Hello!

  This is a test.
```

I want to convert it to LibreOffice (`ODT`) format using Pandoc so that it is formatted according to a template `draft.ott` or `draft-template.odt` both of which are available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/190MUdToNAYXR3X_f2jal7mp87YpTYoZH?usp=sharing).

When I run

```
cat plan.org | \
    pandoc -f org \
       -t odt \
       --template=draft-template.odt \
       --log=plan.odt.log \
       --fail-if-warnings \
       -o plan.odt
```

I get the error

```
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xc6': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

The call

```
cat plan.org | \
    pandoc -f org \
       -t odt \
       --reference-doc=draft-template.odt \
       --log=plan.odt.log \
       --fail-if-warnings \
       -o plan.odt
```

does not generate any errors, but the resulting document `plan.odt` is not formatted according to `draft-template.odt`.

Same problem with

```
cat plan.org | \
    pandoc -f org \
       -t odt \
       --reference-doc=draft.ott \
       --log=plan.odt.log \
       --fail-if-warnings \
       -o plan.odt
```

**How can I make sure that the resulting file `plan.odt` is using the fonts specified in `draft.ott` or `draft-template.odt`?**

I am using `pandoc 2.11.3.1, compiled with pandoc-types 1.22, texmath 0.12.0.3, skylighting 0.10.2, citeproc 0.3.0.1, ipynb 0.1.0.1` under MacOS BigSur 11.1.

**Update 1:** Adding

- `#+ODT_STYLES_FILE: "draft-template.odt"` or
- `#+ODT_STYLES_FILE: "draft.ott"`

to `plan.org` did not solve the problem.

**Update 2:** I tried exporting the default template using `pandoc -D odt > template.odt`, then replacing `Courier New` with `Courier Prime` in `template.odt` and then generating the ODT file using

```
pandoc plan.org \
   -f org \
   -t odt \
   --standalone \
   --template=template.odt \
   --log=plan.odt.log \
   --fail-if-warnings \
   -o plan.odt
```

Still no luck.

**Update 3:** `file plan.org` returns

```
plan.org: ASCII text
```

**Update 4:** The call

```
iconv -t utf-8 plan.org | \
pandoc plan.org \
   -f org \
   -t odt \
   --standalone \
   --template=template.odt \
   --log=plan.odt.log \
   --fail-if-warnings \
   -o plan.odt
```

did not work (`plan.odt` does not have the formatting from template.odt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#character-encoding

try

```
iconv -t utf-8 plan.org | pandoc | iconv -f utf-8
```

(Sorry not to answer this question in a comment. I do not have 50 points)